# What is the use of Zero length array over null ? can anybody explain with example

Tags: java

I was told to use zerolength arrays instead of nulls in the program.But I couldn't find how to use Zerolength array.Please Help me.

Comment: We need more info and context to answer the question.  What is the specific problem?  Can you paste some relevant code in?

Comment: I tried doing this                                                 int arr[]=new arr[0];//it worked                      if(arr==null)//it is showing that it is not null so how can i use //Zerolength arrays instead of null

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The idea, in general, is that if a query returns "no results", all things being equal, it is better to return an empty list (or array) than `null`.

The reason for that is it makes the client code a lot cleaner.  You can still do something like this with an empty array:

```
Account[] accounts = getAccounts();
for ( Account account : accounts ) {
    account.recomputeForInterest();
}
```

If you tried the same with `null` you would get a runtime exception.  You can create an empty array using a few methods:

```
Account[] accounts = {};
accounts = new Account[0];
accounts = new Account[]{};
```

Comment: But How to use the accounts of second type in your code? can I compare it with null? It says it is not null.

Comment: @pavi: You can check if the length is zero: `if (accounts.length == 0) { //...`.  But the point is that you shouldn't have to do that in many cases.  Your logic often won't change for when there are zero accounts as when there are many accounts...you just naturally end up not doing anything.

Comment: @pavi: No problem!  When you feel your question is answered don't forget to accept the answer that you feel best answers your question by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer.  This will let others know not to answer the question since it's resolved, and will give reputation to the answerer you chose.

Answer (score 5):

A zero-length array is simply an array with no contents.  For example, a zero-length array of `int` types would be:

```
int[] myArray = new int[0];
```

Choosing between `null` and an empty array is simply a design decision, depending on how you wish to use the code.  `null` requires an extra check (e.g. `if (myArray != null) { ... }`), but does not actually allocate any space, and therefore may be cheaper if space is of the essence.

Answer (score 2):

A zero length array can be used as an array; you can iterate over its members, for example, or use .length.  You can't do that with null because you will get a null reference exception.

Answer (score 2):

Don't pass nulls!

If you pass a zero length array instead of null then a method using it will be able to iterate over it without causing a null pointer exception. The same is true for any collection class